# What is the meaning of: “If we offend, it is with our good will”

Tags: meaning, phrases, shakespeare

I was reading *A Midsummer Night's Dream; Act-V, Sc.1* . There Peter Quince read the prologue:

> **If we offend, it is with our good will.**
>   That you should think, we come not to offend,
>   But with good will. To show our simple skill,
>   That is the true beginning of our end.
>   Consider then we come but in despite.
>   We do not come as minding to contest you,
>   Our true intent is. All for your delight
>   We are not here. That you should here repent you,

Does the line in bold mean the following?

> *If we happen to offend you, it’s because we want to*

He is saying that they would *offend* with  good intention! They've not come here to make the audience happy! They want to make the audience *sorry* to watch them acting.

In @deadrat's answer he said:

> If we offend (you), it is with our good will.
>   That is, we have good intentions even if we end up offending you.

But, Quince is making sure he is not going to tell these but on the contrary he is clearly saying like '**Hey! I'm a burglar. I'm here to rob you.**'

So, I'm not getting whether he is reading the prologue which should be as pointed by @deadrat or rather darely declaring they are here to make the audience feeling *sorry* for seeing them.

- Is the speaker actually criticizing the drama?
- Is it a prologue or is Quince boldly criticising or offending?
- Could anyone please explain what Quince actually wanted to say?

Comment: There's got to be about 100 analyses of the passage on the web.  Did you search for any of them?

Comment: @Hot Licks: Thanks sir, for that. I always do search before writing any question. I searched [this](https://www.google.co.in/search?newwindow=1&client=opera&hs=y69&q=the+true+beginning+of+our+end+meaning&oq=this+is+the+true+beginning+of+our+end+m&gs_l=serp.1.0.0i22i30l3.11076.11827.0.13531.2.2.0.0.0.0.302.583.2-1j1.2.0....0...1.1.64.serp..1.1.302.C1sYSHEx9jI)but couldn't get any single one that described the meaning.

Comment: Took me about 3 minutes to find this: http://nfs.sparknotes.com/msnd/page_154.html .  And another 4 minutes: http://www.cliffsnotes.com/literature/m/a-midsummer-nights-dream/summary-and-analysis/act-v-scene-1

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about analysing the meaning of a literary extract.

Comment: @sumelic: Hmmm.... could you tell where this should be on-topic?

Comment: @sumelic: Could you give me the link of Area 51 where that `Literature SE` is present?

Comment: SE Literature is defunct, no more, it has ceased to be.  However, this question could be turned to an *on-topic* question if you chose the sentence that troubles the most and explain *why* you are confused by it. Maybe it is the order of words, maybe you don't understand who or what the subject is, maybe the sentence sounds contradictory, etc.. How would you rephrase that line? Then you could ask if your interpretation is correct. TIP: Keep the original text intact but concentrate on the one line. Fingers crossed.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Okay! A good advice.

Comment: Except that the sentences are intentionally nonsense, so analyzing them is pretty close to impossible.

Comment: @HotLicks all the more reason why the question is a valid one, and *could* be on-topic for this site. I think it has potential.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I'm done. Please check this. And thanks for the advice.

Comment: I'm sorry, but now the question/s you are asking is presented in a very confused manner. It seems that deadrat's answer is part of your question. I said to concentrate on ONE line. Maybe someone can edit your post...

Comment: If you don't like my edit, feel free to rollback to the previous version, and/or add/delete  points.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: No, need, sir. It seems you've understood my query.

Comment: Sir is used as a sign of respect  for men, erm... I'm not a man, but I appreciate the sentiment. Usually we just say *thank you*, so I'm glad you feel that the edit was  overall positive.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Okay! This is he way I show respect who helps or intends to help me. I've followed this tradition right from the beginning days at Phys.SE. They help me explain the concept. That means they are acting as _teacher_. That implies I should respect them & thus address them as _sir_. The same reason applies here. You're helping me & you deserve that irrespective of age.

Comment: I am voting (+1) to keep this question as on-topic as it is all about EL&U.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If we offend (you), it is with *our* good will.  That is, we have good intentions even if we end up offending you.
- The true impetus of our purpose:  we start out with good will to end up showing you "our simple skill."
- We are not here to make you end up regretting that you are here.

Comment: Thanks, sir. It seems these lines are written in an intricate manner by Shakespeare. Though I could understand the first & the last line, I've not conceived the middle line. `true beginning`- what does this phrase mean?

Comment: Why the downvote? This did help me. I don't understand why people downvote without citing any reason.

Comment: If you read the commentary, the speaker is an idiot, and is butchering the monologue.  What it all "means" is entirely different from what one might think the supposed author intended.

Comment: @Hot Licks Just read the linked one; well Quince is actually offending them telling the opposite rather than telling the lines intended here in the answer.

Comment: @user36790 Glad it helped.  Don't worry about the driveby downvoters, a plague on this site.